# How to get IP address from HTML form using PHP?

Tags: php, html, ip

For now, I'm trying to receive the ip address of a user that uses a contact form on a website and send that to firebase along with other information. For the HTML and PHP, I used the exact code from this tutorial: http://www.danielpinero.com/how-to-add-ip-address-html-form.

Here is the firebase code:

```
    // Initialize Firebase (ADD YOUR OWN DATA)
var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Reference messages collection
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');

// Listen for form submit
el = document.getElementById('contactForm')
if(el){
  el.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
}

// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get values
  var name = getInputVal('name');
  var email = getInputVal('email');
  var message = getInputVal('msg');
  var ip = getInputVal('ip')

  // Save message
  saveMessage(name, email, message, ip);

  // Clear form
  document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();
}

// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id){
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save message to firebase
function saveMessage(name, email, message, ip){
  var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
  newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    email:email,
    message:message,
    ip:ip
  });
}
```

This is the output im receiving from firebase when clicking submit on my form: 
    [image]

Instead of this, I'd like the user's actual IP to show up. I'm very new to PHP. It'd be great if someone could help me out.

EDIT (index.php):

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" class="cta">
                <div class="col gtr-uniform gtr-50">
                    <div class="col-8 col-12-xsmall inputs"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
                    <div class="col-8 col-12-xsmall inputs"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" /></div>
                    <div class="col-8 col-12-xsmall inputs"><textarea id="msg" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>
                    <input id="ip" type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?=$ip;?>">
                    <div class="col-4 col-12-xsmall"><input type="submit" value="Get Started" class="fit primary" /></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: what filetype is your form? .php or .html?

Comment: Must be a html file, not php script. Need a code excerpt from your form html to see how exactly you put that in.

Comment: I just made the edit to the post. It's index.php and my form code is attached at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you are missing a semicolon near `var ip = getInputVal('ip')`

The second issue is to change this `<input id="ip" type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?=$ip;?>">` to `<input id="ip" type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ip;?>">`
Use this for getting better results for client IP:

```
<?php
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
} 
$ip = get_client_ip();
?>
```

Now as for the js variable you can fill it in various ways:

```
<script>var ip = "<?php echo $ip;?>"; </script>
```

Or you can fill it to the value of a hidden input and get the value though js:

```
<script>var ip = document.getElementById('inputID').value; </script>
```

Comment: Am I doing this in index.php or index.html?

Comment: index.php for sure. You will be using .php files from now on so that the php code works, it doesn't have an effect on the previous html code so will be ok if you just renamed the file.

Comment: How do I see the PHP code in action on the browser? Sorry I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: hahaha it's ok lucky for you I might be the right guy. anw php code won't appear in the browser but as for the php debugging part the easiest way for you now is to just use (echo "111";) for example. Add it after code line to check if they are working. if you see 111 in the browser this means the code is working. or you can echo the variables to see if they are working like use echo $ip to see ip value. variables are the words starting with $ icons ok.

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded MAMP as well and used echo, and it printed out my ip on the browser successfully. Marked the answer as correct.

Comment: Glad I could help. I would recommend Wamp for windows or Lamp for Linux as a server and use brackets as an editor they are much help. Beginners tips :P.